# I have wondered why 'new Thread(new Thread(),"string");' is running correctly

Tags: java, multithreading

This code is running correctly without any login or syntax error; why?

Intentionally no run() method was implemented.

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Thread(),"Name");
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would there be a *login* error?

Comment: The claim that "no run was implemented" is false.

Comment: "Running correctly?"  What do you mean by that?  A program is only _correct_ if it does what it is supposed to do.  What did you intend this program to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the implementation of Thread class it has a default run() method as below,
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (target != null) {
            target.run();
        }
    }

It shows if target is null then do nothing and complete the method call, same is happening with your code, you did not provide any implementation of run() method therefore default one is being executed,

Answer (score 1):

The `run()` in `Thread` is empty, but it still exists. You start the thread, it has nothing to do (due to no `run()` method with logic available) and it will finish. Your example provides an instance of `Thread` as the `Runnable` parameter.

The syntax is correct, but naturally no program would start empty threads, so it's a logical error.